# errors in setting up python-faraday

Tags: package-management, kali-linux

After upgrading from kali 2019 to 2020, while performing an `apt-get upgrade` function in terminal, `python-faraday` cannot be set properly. The following errors are displayed.

```
Setting up faraday (3.10.2-0kali1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/faraday-manage", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('faradaysec==3.10.2', 'console_scripts', 'faraday-manage')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2852, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2443, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2449, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/faraday/manage.py", line 40, in <module>
    from faraday.client.persistence.server.server import _conf, FARADAY_UP, SERVER_URL
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/faraday/client/persistence/server/server.py", line 51, in <module>
    from faraday.client.persistence.server.changes_stream import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/faraday/client/persistence/server/changes_stream.py", line 11, in <module>
    from past.builtins import basestring
ImportError: cannot import name 'basestring' from 'past.builtins' (unknown location)
dpkg: error processing package faraday (--configure):
 installed faraday package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-faraday:
 python-faraday depends on faraday; however:
  Package faraday is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-faraday (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 faraday
 python-faraday
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not trying to use it or install it, why don't you just remove it? 
Try

```
sudo apt remove faraday       && sudo apt remove python-faraday
```

or if you want it, try

```
sudo apt purge python-faraday && sudo apt install python-faraday -y
```

Comment: Your answer is fine, but the OP is not clear about what he/she is asking help for. Probably why this question has gone unanswered for 4+ months.